# Drawing a clock with python

Tags: python, svg, coordinates, clock, angle

I am making a program with python to draw a clock in svg file format. The problem is I don't get the short lines showing the time to right places. What is wrong with my code?

Here is how it looks like in Inkscape:

[Image of clock in Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke9Oe.png)

And here is my code:

```
import svgwrite
import math

#Definitions
filename = 'inkscape_007.svg'
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 1000

# Open the drawing

dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(filename)
dwg.viewbox(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)

#Drawing code
circle = dwg.circle(center=(500, 500), r='250', fill='none',stroke='darkred', 
stroke_width=10)
dwg.add(circle)
dwg.save()

def x_coord(angle,radius,center_x):
    x = radius * math.cos(angle) + center_x
    x = round(x)
    return x

def y_coord(angle,radius,center_y):
    y = radius * math.sin(angle) + center_y
    y = round(y)
   return y

ang = 0
line = dwg.line(start=(x_coord(ang,250,500),y_coord(ang,250,500)), end= 
(x_coord(ang,220,500),y_coord(ang,220,500)), stroke='black', stroke_width=10)
dwg.add(line)
dwg.save()

ang = 90
line = dwg.line(start=(x_coord(ang,250,500),y_coord(ang,250,500)), end= 
(x_coord(ang,220,500),y_coord(ang,220,500)), stroke='black', stroke_width=10)
dwg.add(line)
dwg.save()

ang = 180
line = dwg.line(start=(x_coord(ang,250,500),y_coord(ang,250,500)), end= 
(x_coord(ang,220,500),y_coord(ang,220,500)), stroke='black', stroke_width=10)
dwg.add(line)
dwg.save()

ang = 360
line = dwg.line(start=(x_coord(ang,250,500),y_coord(ang,250,500)), end= 
(x_coord(ang,220,500),y_coord(ang,220,500)), stroke='black', stroke_width=10)
dwg.add(line)
dwg.save()

#Save the file
dwg.save()
```

Comment: All of Python's trigonometric functions operate on radians, not degrees.

Comment: From first glance it looks like what's missing here is the time conversion from hours to angular co-ordinates (radians or degrees). I recently made similar clock in JavaScript.. I don't know if this will be helpful or not but you can see my code here: https://github.com/ccnmtl/astro-interactives/blob/master/sun-motion-simulator/src/Clock.jsx#L61  This renders the clock seen here: https://ccnmtl.github.io/astro-interactives/sun-motion-simulator/

Comment: As Jason Harper suggests, you need to pass those trig functions angles in radians, not degrees. The math module has `degrees` and `radians` functions to perform the conversions.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I added to both functions one line: angle = math.radians(angle) and that seems to resolve the problem.